# Formula for calculating number of hours between 2 Date/Time fields

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime, field-update

**Problem:** I am trying to figure out the time in hours it takes for a Lead to be contacted after the Lead record is created

**Steps Taken:**

1- Created a custom read-only Date/Time field called *First_Contacted_Date__c*

2- Built a Flow that sets the *First_Contacted_Date__c* to the date/time the first Task is completed

**Where I Am Stuck:**

The final part I need to solve is to create a number formula field on the Lead that calculates the number of hours between the 2 Date/Time fields *First_Contacted_Date__c* and *CreatedDate*.

Does not need to be business hours, just the total hours. I have found ways to create a text field that calculates number of business hours. But ideally, we need the number of hours as a number field.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how it can be done?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the two fields, subtract them, and divide by 24 (subtraction calculates days):

```
(First_Contacted_Date__c-CreatedDate)/24
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the decimal places to show up as well? For instance 0.5 hours = 30 min etc. When I use this formula and put the decimal places as 2, I get no value for the decimal

Comment: Please disregard. I got it: (DATETIMEVALUE(First_Contacted_Date__c) - DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDate))*24

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this -

```
VALUE(TEXT)
```

It will convert text into number

Comment: The other approach could be - if difference between number of days is less than 1, other wise you can use add 24*number .
`HOUR(TIMEVALUE(First_Contacted_Date__c ) - HOUR(TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate)))`

Comment: Is there a way to get the decimal places to show up as well? For instance 0.5 hours = 30 min etc. When I use this formula and put the decimal places as 2, I get no value for the decimal

Comment: Please disregard. I got it: (DATETIMEVALUE(First_Contacted_Date__c) - DATETIMEVALUE(CreatedDate))*24

Answer (score 0):

VALUE(
TEXT(HOUR( TIMEVALUE(Out__c) ) -  HOUR(TIMEVALUE(IN__c) ))
+
'.'
+
TEXT(IF( MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Out__c)) < MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(IN__c)) , MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(IN__c)) -  MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Out__c)) , MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(Out__c)) -  MINUTE(TIMEVALUE(IN__c))))
)

With this formula you can calculate the exact time between 2 date/time data type